# React-Router-dom redirect breaks header link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating basic search submit form with react-router-dom, but whenever I click on 'Search' button, I get SearchRes component, but after that it's impossible to get home component back, after I click on home link in header url changes back to '/' but view doesn't.(it only gets back to original view after I click on about and then home) Any way I can get home link working after submitting?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Link}from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home';
import About from './about'
const App=()=>{
return(<div>
 <Router>
   <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
   <Link to='/about'>About</Link>

   <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
   <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
 </Router>
</div>)
}

export default App
```

home.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

import SearchRes from './results';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Redirect}from 'react-router-dom';


const Home=()=>{
const [redirect, setRedirect]=useState(false);
const [term,setTerm]=useState('');

if(redirect){
    return(<Router>
        <Redirect to={'/search/'+term}/>
        <Route exact path='/Search/:txt' component={SearchRes}/>
    </Router>)
}


return(<div>
    <input type='text' onChange={(event)=>setTerm(event.target.value)}/>
    <input type='button' value='search' onClick={()=>setRedirect(true)}/>
</div>)
}

export default Home;
```

results.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const SearchRes=({match})=>{
return(<div>
    <h3>{match.params.txt}</h3>
</div>)
}

export default withRouter(SearchRes);
```

Comment: Why are you using `Router` again isnide `home.js`, You can remove it as the parent component has `Router`.

Comment: Thanks Panther, after modifying index.js file and putting paths inside ReactDom.Render your advice worked.